# Loading text file into listbox

Tags: c#, file, text, listbox

What I am wanting to achieve is loading a text file into a listbox. It seems simple enough but I need to recognise in the text file when there is a new line, and each new line needs to be a new item in the listbox.

If this is possible, a reply would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can use `StreamReader.ReadLine()` to automatically read single lines, as opposed to detecting the new line characters yourself.

Comment: @Jason I tried that, it loads it all into one listbox item. I used the following code.

`listBox1.Items.Add(StreamReader.ReadLine());`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        lines.Add(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
  OpenFileDialog f = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (f.ShowDialog() ==DialogResult.OK)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f.OpenFile()))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(line);

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
listboxObject.DataSource = File.ReadAllLines("PathToYourFileHere");
```

Answer (score 2):

ADD items From A Multiline Txt To ListBox

Array array = system.io.file.readalllines(filepath);

foreach(string i in array)
{

listboxname.items.add(i)

}

Answer (score 1):

You can read all text (file.ReadAllText or Alllines), I don't have a compiler here.

Then add them to the list box, it is advised to trim the lines to get rid of whitespace at the beginning and end of each line.