# Outputing log file to WPF listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to display my log file to a `ListBox` on my `WPF application`. I have modified [this](http://matijabozicevic.com/blog/csharp-net-development/csharp-monitor-directory-activity-using-fileSystemWatcher-class) sample application to do exactly that. However I have a question regarding displaying of the contents of the file.

```
void DisplayFileSystemWatcherInfo(System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes watcherChangeTypes, string name, string oldName = null)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { AddListLine(string.Format("{0} -> {1} - {2}", watcherChangeTypes.ToString(), name, DateTime.Now)); }));
}
```

It prints only when the file has changed. I would rather have the contents of the `log file` to be displayed on the screen. How do I do that?

Comment: What does AddListLine do?

Answer (score 1):

What you have right now is a way to monitor changes in a file and add these changes to a ListBox.

If you want to read a file and add its content to a ListBox, [this question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531375/loading-text-file-into-listbox).
Here's a code sample from it:

```
listboxObject.DataSource = File.ReadAllLines("PathToYourFileHere");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace ListBox with

```
<TextBox Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="txtContent" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="549" IsReadOnly="True" Text="" AcceptReturn="True"></TextBox>
```

And change the code to this

```
void DisplayFileSystemWatcherInfo(System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes watcherChangeTypes, string name, string oldName = null)
        {    
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { txtContent.Text= System.IO.File.ReadAllText("filePath"); }));    
        }
```